# Any Javadoc style documentation tool for MyBatis XML sqlmaps?

Tags: java, xml, javadoc, mybatis

We have a project with a lot of MyBatis XML sqlmaps. Is there any tool/plugin/trick to comment them and generate documentation in Javadoc style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an option u can write comments in YourMapper.java interface in usual javadoc style